# Android : gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I have a gridview in one screen and in gridview i am displaying all the images which is present in SDCard this is working fine. Now what i want to do is when i click on any of gridview images it should go to next activity and should display that particular image in full screen. I have referred some other link and tried but not getting proper solution.

```
 public class Gallary_Images extends Activity {

private Cursor cursor;
private int columnIndex;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery_images);

    // Set up an array of the Thumbnail Image ID column we want
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID };
    // Create the cursor pointing to the SDCard
    cursor = managedQuery(
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection,
            null, // Return all rows
            null, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);
    // Get the column index of the Thumbnails Image ID
    columnIndex = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);

    GridView sdcardImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    sdcardImages.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    // Set up a click listener
    sdcardImages.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    ViewGallery_Photo.class);
            i.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;

    public ImageAdapter(Context localContext) {
        context = localContext;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView picturesView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            picturesView = new ImageView(context);
            // Move cursor to current position
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            // Get the current value for the requested column
            int imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
            // Set the content of the image based on the provided URI
            picturesView.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ""
                            + imageID));
            picturesView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            picturesView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            picturesView
                    .setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
        } else {
            picturesView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        return picturesView;
    }
}
}
```

This is my gridview class where i am calling next activity. Now i don't know how should i get the images in next activity. Please help...

Answer (score 0):

First thing that you must try is a put an URi of image in your intent like this

```
intent.putExtra("imageUri", imageUri.toString());
```

where imageUri is Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ""+ imageID));

but before this you must know your imageID, so the whole code must be like this

```
sdcardImages.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,long id) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ViewGallery_Photo.class);
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        int imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
        Uri imageUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
        ""+ imageID)); 
        intent.putExtra("imageUri", imageUri.toString());
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply whizzzkey... I will try this code and let you know that this is working or not..

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below:
Add data filed in your projection string.

> ```
>     String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
>                 MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
> ```

```
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, android.view.View v,
            int position, long id) {
       Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ViewGallery_Photo.class);

        cursor = managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,
                null, null, null);
        final int dataColumnIndex = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        final int idColumIndex = actualimagecursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        filename = cursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);

        i.putExtra("imagePath", filename );
        startActivity(i);
```